# keywords added by exiv2 not found

Tags: iptc, exiv2

I export images using Lightroom, with keywords in the IPTC metadata.

I then use exiv2 to add keywords.

I then upload my images to an online website. The website sees the keywords added by Lightroom, but not the keywords added by exiv2. I can see the keywords added by exiv2 in the windows or linux file explorer, so I know they have been properly embedded in the image.

What might be causing this website to be "blind" to the changes made to the files?

Answer (score 0):

The website is reading metadata from xmp and not iptc

Answer (score 0):

The wonderful thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from.  In the case of keywords, there are two standardized locations:

```
Iptc.Application2.Keywords
Xmp.dc.subject
```

and five application-specific locations:

```
Exif.Image.XPKeywords
Xmp.acdsee.categories
Xmp.digiKam.TagsList
Xmp.MicrosoftPhoto.LastKeywordXMP
Xmp.MicrosoftPhoto.LastKeywordIPTC
```